# How does the steam market work for different currencies?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards, steam-community-market

I searched on web and read many article but i still cant understand How do the steam market and its currency converter work? I also wonder why there are so many spikes in some lower valued items like [this](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Shadow%20Case).

I came across an interesting result when i give an order then removed it. [Here is what happened and the screenshots in order.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZsir.jpg)

I gave 10 order for 0.20 TRY and i show it is converted to 0.05$ but it says 0.3$ in activity. (Real currency is 0.20 TRY = 0.037 USD ~ 0.04$) Both 0.20 try and 0.05$ was highest bid on the market.

I thought activity might use different converter and its just for info this might not effect anything but it looks like its not because i found one more thing. I gave 10 order for 0.36TRY another card and it highest bid order like before in my currency i was waiting to be listed for 0.08$ but it is listed for 0.06$.

There was only 1 order for 0.36TRY and 1 order for 0.08$ on the market before i gave order.

I show 11 order 0.36TRY , 1 order for 0.08$ 10 order for 0.06$ after gave my order.

I would understand if the difference was 0.01$ and i would think its rounding issue but it looks like it not. Does anyone have an opinion why that happens? You can try it in your currency and we can discuss.

Note: I did not use steam addons to convert currencies i used chrome incognito tab to see prices in dollar.

Comment: Not sure if this is on-topic, but I do know Valve takes a percentage of any transaction: in this case the $0.02 difference. And I think the different and seemingly incongruent exchange rates have to do with lots of things: from national tax rates to the psychology behind prices.

Comment: There is no problem between market price and price i got after sale so valve cut is not related here. I could not understand how national tax rates might result situation above.

Comment: I've read (I think about a similar platform) that euros and dollars, for example, are regularly not converted according to exchange rates, but on a one to one basis (what's $19.99 in the US will be €19.99 in the EU). But I see now this has nothing to do with your question (which is hard to read). It is strange. You mean when you put a .36₺ item up for sale, it showed as $.06, but you got .36₺ when you sold it?

Comment: I am getting from selling exactly the same amount as shown in my currency but this is also not the case here. The problem is how conversion works and how do they put my item in order with other currencies.

Answer (score 1):

Valve not only rounds to the nearest USD cent in the converted currency, they then also tack on their own fees based on the price. This is also rounded to the nearest cent.

Due to how both of these roundings work, occasionally a market item can be listed out of order when it comes to sorting items by price. That listed price is ultimately what you pay, so both parties get what they agreed to in their own currency.

Comment: That link leads me to some ad pages. There are no currencies...

Comment: Thanks, removed the link since it appears that the domain is no longer maintained.